# Is there a way I can reset the value of a whole instance of class with that class method?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way I can reset the value of a whole instance of class with that class method?

I mean something like this:

```
export class User {
    // ...,

    reset() {
        this = new User();
    }
}
```

Trying it that way, I'm getting this error:

> The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a
> property access.ts(2364);

**EDIT:**

I think a work around for that (considering @vr. suggestion) could be:

```
export class User {
    // ...,

    reset() {
        Object.assign(this, new User());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, but you can reset the state of the class. Reset its members, etc.

Comment: There's a popular design pattern called Memento to handle cases like this: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento